# Reading only integers from text file and adding them

Tags: java

Lets say I have a textfile.txt with contents:

```
x   y   z   sum
3   6   5
6   7   8
```

I want to add each row, `3 + 6 + 5` and `6 + 7 + 8`, and output the sum into a new text file in a format like this:

```
x   y   z   sum
3   6   5   14
6   7   8   21
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));                
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("text_output.txt");

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
       String currentLine = s.nextLine();
       String words[] = currentLine.split(" ");


       int sum = 0;
       boolean isGood = true;
       for(String str : words) {
          try {
             sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
          }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { };  
               continue;}

       if (isGood && sum != 0) {
           System.out.println(sum);
           output.print(sum);              
           output.close();

       }

    }
}
```

Which will print all the correct sums in the console, but will only write the first or last sum to the new file. How do I get it to write all the sum values to the file?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Just having difficulty getting the sum of the correct numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Make a `sum` to add up the numbers, and add `continue` to skip to the next line on error:

```
int sum = 0;
boolean isGood = true;
for(String str : words) {
    try {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // If any of the items fails to parse, skip the entire line
        isGood = false;
        continue;
    };
}
if (isGood) {
    // If everything parsed, print the sum
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So first you are going to want to make FileWriter and BufferedWriter.  This will allow you to write to a new text file.

You can do this by:

```
FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter("outputfile.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputFile);
```

I would then change you're for loop a little bit.  I would declare a sum variable outside of the for loop.
Like this:

```
 int sum = 0;
           for(String str : words) {
```

This will allow us to use it later outside of the for loop.  Then in for loop we are going to want to write the value it is getting to the textfile. Then add it to our sum value.
Like this:

```
bw.write(str+ " ");
sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
```

After we have done this we can simply write our sum to the file.  You want to put this out side of the for loop because that is when it has gone though the entire line and added all of the integer together!
You can write the sum like this:

```
bw.write(sum+"\n");
```

Finally you are going to want to close the BufferedWriter.  You are going to want to do this outside of you're while loop or it will close after it reads and writes the first line!
Close it like this:

```
bw.close();
```

And then you are good to go!  You might have to refresh you're project to see the new text file it creates though.